# How to pass a dynamically created component as ng-content of a dynamically created component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making a modal for our library, and I am not sure how to do this, but I would like to use `viewRef.createComponent` to create a component (A), then I would like to create another component (B) inside of component A and have component A use `<ng-content>` to get the the items from component B.

Basically Component A is a template for the modal and Component B is what to fill the modal with.

So, first I have sections `modal-header` and `modal-content`. These are the two directives I would like to grab from component B.

**Note:** The last code block in this post is where the issue is located (see the comment).

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9b5un2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-popup%2Fmodal-popup.component.ts)

```js
@Directive({selector: 'modal-header'})
export class ModalHeader {}

@Directive({selector: 'modal-content'})
export class ModalContent {}
```

Component A's template looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <h4 *ngIf="modalHeader" mat-dialog-title>
    <ng-content select="modal-header, [modal-header]"></ng-content>
  </h4>
  <mat-dialog-content *ngIf="modalContent">
    <ng-content select="modal-content, [modal-content]"></ng-content>
  </mat-dialog-content>
</div>
```

Component B's template looks like this:

```html
<modal-header>Hello World</modal-header>
<modal-content>This is some cool stuff</modal-content>
```

Then in a service I am using `MatDialog` to open the modal with the above html which works:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {
  constructor(private readonly dialog: MatDialog) {}

  create<T>(component: Type<T>) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalPopupComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.componentType = component;
  }
}
```

That service then opens this component which will then create component A which works, then I want to inject component B into `const main`.

```js
@Component({ template: `<div #outlet></div>` })
export class ModalPopupComponent {
  @ViewChild('outlet', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) outlet!: ViewContainerRef;

  componentType!: Type<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const main = this.outlet.createComponent<ModalComponent>(ModalComponent);
    // How do I inject `this.componentType` into `main`?
  }
}
```

In `createComponent`, there is a `projectableNodes` option, can I pass the component through that option?

I tried doing this as well, but this just appends component B to the end of component A.

```js
    const main = this.outlet.createComponent<ModalComponent>(ModalComponent);

    const ref = main.injector.get(ViewContainerRef);
    ref.createComponent(this.componentType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using `projectableNodes` in the create component and passing an array of html elements.

1. Create the component that we want to get the nodes from.
2. Get the elements from the newly created component.
3. Pass the elements to the template element which will replace instances of `<ng-content>`; where the first `<ng-content>` matches the first item in the array, the second `<ng-content>` matches the second item, and so on.

The class would then look something like this:

```js
@Component({ template: `<div #outlet></div>` })
export class ModalPopupComponent {
  @ViewChild('outlet', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) outlet!: ViewContainerRef;

  componentType!: Type<any>;
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const user = this.outlet.createComponent(this.componentType);
    const el = user.main.location.nativeElement;
    const header = el.querySelectorAll('modal-header');
    const content = el.querySelectorAll('modal-content');
    
    this.outlet.createComponent<ModalComponent>(ModalComponent, {
      projectableNodes: [header, content]
    });
  }
}
```

The projectable nodes would then replace the `<ng-content>` in this template:

**Note:** This doesn't seem to work if the content is wrapped within an `*ngIf`.

**Note:** Placing the `<ng-content>` in an `<ng-template>` might work and then use `ngTemplateOutlet` to show it (untested).

```html
<div>
  <h4 mat-dialog-title>
    <!-- The first item in the array -->
    <ng-content select="modal-header, [modal-header]"></ng-content>
  </h4>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <!-- The second item in the array -->
    <ng-content select="modal-content, [modal-content]"></ng-content>
  </mat-dialog-content>
</div>
```